# Mistake in my calculation in the Broken Stick problem?

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value, uniform-distribution

The well-known Broken Stick problem goes as follows:

> Given a stick with length $1,$ if we broke it at two points randomly, then what is the probability that the three pieces can form a triangle?

It is well-known that the answer is $\frac{1}{4}.$
However, my calculations below are not able to get the answer (I got $\frac{1}{8}$ instead).
I am not sure where is my mistake.

Let $X,Y$ be random variables denoting the length of first and second piece respectively. 
Then they follow the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ with probability density function $1.$
So,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{formed triangle}) & = \mathbb{P}(\frac{1}{2} \leq X+Y\leq 1, 0\leq X\leq \frac{1}{2}, 0\leq Y\leq \frac{1}{2}) \\
&= \int\int_C dxdy  = \text{area of }C
\end{align*}
$$
where $C = \{ (x,y)\in [0,1]^2: \frac{1}{2} \leq x+y\leq 1, 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}, 0\leq y\leq \frac{1}{2} \}.$
However, clearly the area of $C$ is 
$$\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}.$$
I am not sure where is my mistake.

Comment: The total area of the triangle in the first quadrant (formed by your constraints) is $1/2$ so your area o $1/8$ with respect to the total area of $1/2$ fits $4$ times. In other words, the probability of landing in your $1/8$ is 25%. That's how I view your set up and subsequent computation from a geometric stand point

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is not independent (for example if $X$ happens to have length $1/2-1/10000$ then the probability that $Y$ has length $\leq 1/2$ is much greater than $1/2$).

A correct version of your kind of reasoning is: $X$ is the length of the first piece, chosen uniformly from $[0,1]$, and the $Y$ is the length of second piece, chosen uniformly from $[0,1-X]$. So the integral to be calculated is $1/8$ as you say, but to correct the calculation we need to recall that our probability is conditional on $Y\leq 1-X$, so we need to divide it by the probability of that happening, which is $1/2$.

Comment: In this case, how to obtain the joint probability density of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: It would be good if you can show the calculations.